# Цикл внутри try...catch, как написать красивый код?

Tags: c#, исключения, vkontakte-api, captcha

Код примерно следующий:

```
    public void AntigateAuthorize(int appId, string email, string password, Settings settings, string antigateKey)
    {
        var authorizationCompleted = false;

        try
        {
            Authorize(appId, email, password, settings);
            authorizationCompleted = true;
        }
        catch (CaptchaNeededException exception)
        {
            var captchaSid = exception.Sid;
            var image = GetImageFromUrl(exception.Img.AbsoluteUri);

            try
            {
                const int numberOfAuthorizationRetries = 5;
                var retryAuthorizationsCount = numberOfAuthorizationRetries;
                do
                {
                    var anticaptcha = new AntiCaptcha(antigateKey);
                    try
                    {
                        var captchaKey = anticaptcha?.GetAnswer(image);

                        if (captchaKey != null)
                        {
                            Authorize(appId, email, password, settings, captchaSid, captchaKey);
                            authorizationCompleted = true;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Logger.Error("Ответ от сервера Antigate не получен.");
                        }
                    }
                    catch (CaptchaNeededException)
                    {
                        Logger.Trace("Капча распознана неверно.");
                        anticaptcha.FalseCaptcha();
                        retryAuthorizationsCount--;
                        if (retryAuthorizationsCount == 0)
                        {
                            Logger.Trace("Заданное количество попыток авторизации исчерпано.");
                            throw;
                        }
                    }
                } while (!authorizationCompleted && retryAuthorizationsCount > 0);
            }
            catch (AntigateErrorException aee)
            {
                Logger.Error("Ошибка Antigate: {0}", aee.Message);
            }
        }
        catch (VkApiAuthorizationException)
        {
            Logger.Error("Не удалось авторизовать приложение. Неправильный логин или пароль.");
        }
        catch (VkApiException)
        {
            Logger.Error("В процессе попытки авторизации произошла неизвестная ошибка.");
        }
    }

    public static Image GetImageFromUrl(string url)
    {
        using (var stream = ((HttpWebResponse)((HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url)).GetResponse()).GetResponseStream())
            return stream == null ? null : Image.FromStream(stream);
    }
```

Проблема в том, если обрабатывать ошибку CaptchaNeededException однократно, то всё получается, а если в цикле - получается плохо и некрасиво.

Comment: Вам не нравится именно качество/читаемость кода, или он ещё и неправильно работает?

Comment: Не нравится именно качество/читаемость. Код работает.

Comment: Хм, А если вы приходите во внутренний `catch (CaptchaNeededException)`, вам случайно не нужно подменить картнику?

Comment: Да, куча вложенных try...catch, смотрится ужасно. Следует последовать ниже приведенному примеру. И разбить функцию на несколько.
Одно из ключевых правил, хорошего кода: функция должна делать ровно то о чем говорит её имя.
Некоторые еще добавляют к этому, что она должна быть не больше 1 экрана.
Много вложенных блоков тоже не хорошо. Потому что по сути блок и есть функция.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно попробовать разбить на мелкие функции. Например, так:

```
public void AntigateAuthorize(
        int appId, string email, string password,
        Settings settings, string antigateKey)
{
    try
    {
        try
        {
            Authorize(appId, email, password, settings);
        }
        catch (CaptchaNeededException exception)
        {
            AuthorizeWithCaptcha(appId, email, password, settings, exception);
        }
    }
    catch (AntigateErrorException)
    {
        // ?
    }
    catch (VkApiAuthorizationException)
    {
        Logger.Error(
            "Не удалось авторизовать приложение. Неправильный логин или пароль.");
    }
    catch (VkApiException)
    {
        Logger.Error(
            "В процессе попытки авторизации произошла неизвестная ошибка.");
    }
}
```

Вспомогательные функции:

```
private void AuthorizeWithCaptchaOnceImpl(
        int appId, string email, string password,
        Settings settings, CaptchaNeededException reason,
        AntiCaptcha anticaptcha)
{
    var captchaSid = reason.Sid;
    var image = GetImageFromUrl(reason.Img.AbsoluteUri);

    try
    {
        var captchaKey = anticaptcha.GetAnswer(image);

        if (captchaKey == null)
        {
            Logger.Error("Ответ от сервера Antigate не получен.");
            throw new NoAntigateResponceException();
        }

        Authorize(appId, email, password, settings, captchaSid, captchaKey);
    }
    catch (CaptchaNeededException)
    {
        Logger.Trace("Капча распознана неверно.");
        anticaptcha.FalseCaptcha();
        throw;
    }
}

void AuthorizeWithCaptcha(
        int appId, string email, string password,
        Settings settings, CaptchaNeededException exception)
{
    try
    {
        var anticaptcha = new AntiCaptcha(antigateKey);
        const int numberOfAuthorizationRetries = 5;

        CaptchaNeededException currentException = exception;

        for (int retry = 0; retry < numberOfAuthorizationRetries; retry++)
        {
            try 
            {           
                AuthorizeWithCaptchaOnceImpl(
                        appId, email, password,
                        settings, currentException, anticaptcha);
                return;
            }
            catch (CaptchaNeededException ex)
            {
                currentException = ex;
            }
            catch (NoAntigateResponceException ex)
            {
                // nothing to do, just retry
            }
        }
        throw new RetryNumberExceededException();
    }
    catch (AntigateErrorException aee)
    {
        Logger.Error("Ошибка Antigate: {0}", aee.Message);
        throw;
    }
}
```

Заметьте, что я немного поменял логику. Например, после неудачного распознавания капчи теперь картинка меняется. Также, в результате превышения разрешённого количества попыток распознавания выбрасывается исключение (хотя, возможно, вы захотите вернуть `bool` из функции).

Comment: Раз уж речь идет о качестве/читаемости кода, я бы переименовал метод `TryAuthorizeWithAnticaptcha`. А то он, вроде как, try, но в то же время бросает исключение.

Comment: @Vlad: Согласен, а как лучше?

Comment: Хороший вопрос. :) Ну, например, также, как и нижний метод. Сделать перегрузку.

Comment: @Vlad: Нееее, у них разный смысл. «Попытка распознать капчу и авторизоваться» и «полная авторизация в случае капчи».

Comment: Первый метод тоже выполняет "полную авторизацию в случае капчи". Второй метод завершает работу после того, как первый отработал без исключений.

Comment: @Vlad Ну, смотря что мы называем полной авторизацией. С повторениями или без? Возможно, тогда покатит имя: `AuthorizeOnceAfterCaptchaReq` и `AuthorizeWithRetryAfterCaptchaReq`?

Comment: Позвольте нам [продолжить обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23048/discussion-between-vlad-and-vladd).

Comment: @VladD, добавил свой вариант, глянете?

Comment: Не далеко ушло от варианта ТС, агрегация эксепшенов конечно круто, но тем не менее еще слишком много ветвления и нет SRP

Comment: @Sam_Fisher: Если вы хотите развернуть предметную дискуссию, вы можете указать пример кода в вашем ответе.

Answer (score 1):

Есть такая рекомендация: для упрощения читаемости кода блоки `if`/`try`/`catch`/`finally`/`for`/`foreach`/`while` должны содержать как можно меньше кода, в идеале -- вызов одного метода.

Еще одна рекомендация: соблюдать минимальную вложенность кода.

Например, у вас есть код:

```
public void Foo()
{
    try
    {
        FooInternal();
    }
    catch (Exception1)
    {
        ...
    }
    catch (Exception2)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Цель этого метода: вызов некоторого кода и обработка ошибок. При этом метод не перегружен подробностями о том, какой код вызывается. В свою очередь метод `FooInternal` не будет перегружен информацией о возможных ошибках и их обработке.

---

К вашему коду. Для внешнего блока try эти рекомендации у вас соблюдены:

```
try
{
    Authorize(appId, email, password, settings);
    authorizationCompleted = true;
}
```

Теперь осталось вынести содержимое `catch (CaptchaNeededException exception)` в отдельный метод. В нем -- в свою очередь вынести содержимое блоков `try/catch` в отдельные методы.

От развесистой структуры блоков `try/catch`, к сожалению, совсем избавиться не удастся -- такова логика.

Answer (score 1):

Я бы вынес логику отдельно, т.к.  в коде присутствуют другие методы не отвечающие за авторизацию, нет следования принципу SRP и не будет reuse.

К примеру класс `class Antigate Service`, метод `TryAuthenticate` который будет возвращать `bool` и `out AuthenticationResult`.

По крайней мере мне так видится, избавление в будущем от дублирования

И вообще следует избегать ветвления кода(даже если это try/catch)

Answer (score 1):

Переделал сейчас примерно следующим образом (убрал для примера лишние catch):

```
public void AuthorizeEx(
        int appId,
        string email,
        string password,
        Settings settings,
        int captchaRecognitionCount = MaxCaptchaRecognitionCount,
        AntiCaptcha antiCaptcha = null,
        CaptchaNeededException previousException = null)
    {
        if (captchaRecognitionCount < 0) return;

        var captchaSid = previousException?.Sid;
        var captchaKey = previousException == null ? null : antiCaptcha?.GetAnswer(GetImageFromUrl(previousException?.Img?.AbsoluteUri));

        try
        {
            Authorize(appId, email, password, settings, captchaSid, captchaKey);
        }
        catch (CaptchaNeededException currentException)
        {
            AuthorizeEx(appId, email, password, settings, captchaRecognitionCount - 1, antiCaptcha, currentException);
        }
    }

    private static Image GetImageFromUrl([CanBeNull] string url)
    {
        if (url == null) return null;
        using (var stream = ((WebRequest.Create(url))?.GetResponse())?.GetResponseStream())
        {
            return stream == null ? null : Image.FromStream(stream);
        }
    }
```

Итог: код обработки капчи идёт отдельно, красиво. Из минусов - использование рекурсии, но так ли это страшно, если я ограничиваю её уровень?
Если нехорошо, то как развернуть?

Comment: Рекурсия не страшна, но по идее её можно развернуть в цикл по количеству попыток. Это вроде бы правильно т. к. у нас нет рекурсии в постановке задачи, а есть повторы, т. е. итерации. Код будет выглядеть как-то так: `while (remaining-- > 0) { try { Authorize(); return; } catch (ex) { /*nothing*/ } }`. Лучше ли это читаемо — судить вам.

Comment: Надеюсь этот код не в контроллере ?
Если да, то обычно за такое по пальцам бьют

Comment: @Sam_Fisher, нет, конечно! А вообще от рекурсии я избавился давно в своём проекте.